# Regex in rails to match [\w] and "-" but not numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I want to write a regular expression for First name validation . 
The regular expression should include all alphabets (latin/french/german characters etc.). However I want to exclude numbers from it and also allow `-`. 
So basically it is `\w` (minus) numbers (plus) `-`.

Please help.

Comment: Also try http://rubular.com best resource to test your ruby regexs.

Answer (score 6):

```
^[\p{L}-]+$
```

`\p{L}` matches [any kind of letter from any language](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, Ruby doesn't support Unicode properties (at least until version 1.8), so you might need to use

```
^(?:[^\W\d_]|-)+$
```

Explanation: `[^\W\d_]` matches any letter (literally it means "Match a character that is neither a non-alphanumeric character, a digit, or an underscore"). In this case, a double negative is the right thing to use. Since we're using a negated character class, we then need to allow the `-` by alternation.

**Caveat:** From [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) it looks like Ruby only matches ASCII characters with the `\w` shorthand, so this regex might not work as intended. I don't have Ruby installed here, but on rubular.com this regex is working correctly.

The alternate solution

```
^[[:alpha:]-]+$
```

should match non-ASCII characters according to regular-expressions.info and RegexBuddy, but on rubular.com it's not working.

Comment: Maybe coz its not ruby specific?

Comment: @Shripad K: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a ruby specific solution to your validation problem then you can use this:

```
^[\D-]+$
```

You can check this permalink here:

http://rubular.com/r/VrAIB4TkwJ

I have made this a community wiki so that everyone can try it out and better the regex if required.

Hope this helps. Cheers :)

Comment: Not really. This matches everything but digits, including strings like `!"§$%&` - not what Dinesh needs.